# How to monitor how much resources a query uses in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDB on Ubuntu 14.04 and I need to test CPU/Memory usage of different types of queries.

I'm wondering weather there is a script I can write or method I can use. I have tried using iotop however it doesn't to be useful. some guidance will be appreciated

Comment: have you checked mongotop, mongostat, and the integrated mongodb profiler?

Comment: I have tried all those but they are not giving me the results I need. all i need really are CPU and/or memory usage data, for each query I test. for example I run a query, then my tool/script will return the cpu/memory usage. @mnemosyn

Comment: Your OS has tools to monitor the CPU and memory usage of the process, in addition to the information you can get from mongotop, mongostat, the profiler, and db.currentOp. CPU and memory usage are really for the process, not a specific operation, and it doesn't exactly make sense to talk about how much CPU or memory one query used.